# Reliable and "as portable as possible" way to map from device name to mountpoint in Python

Tags: python, linux, macos, unix

I want to be able to take a device name (eg: `/dev/disk2`) and determine where (if anywhere) it's mounted (eg: `/mnt/cdrom` or `/Volumes/RANDLABEL`) in Python.

One way I can do this is to run `df` or `mount` and then parse the output, but this seems pretty cheesy and unreliable. For example, `mount` uses `" on "` as the delimiter between the device and the mountpoint. While very unlikely, either of these could potentially include that very string, making the output ambiguous.

On Linux I could read `/proc/mounts`, but this won't work on Mac OS X, for example.

So I'm looking for a way to find the mountpoint for a device in a way that's reliable (ie: can deal with arbitrary (legal) device/mountpoint names) and is "as portable as possible". (I'm guessing that portability to Windows might not be possible -- I'm not sure if it even has an analogous concept of device mountpoints.) I particularly want something that will work on both Linux and OS X.

Comment: Remember that the same device can have more than one name, and - on some platforms - more than one mountpoint.

Comment: @Zanchey That's fine. I just need to find any mountpoint given the device name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From my comment above: `mtab` is the standard Linux way. It doesn't exist on FreeBSD, Mac OS X or Solaris. The former two have the `getfsstat(2)` and `getmntinfo(2)` system calls; on Solaris you can use `getmntent(3C)`. Unfortunately the list of currently-mounted filesystems is not defined by POSIX AFAIK, so it is wildly different on different platforms.)

There's the experimental `mount` module in the [PSI package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PSI) from PyPI, which appears to attempt to bundle all the platform-specific methods into a simple abstraction, and which is advertised as working on Mac OS X (Darwin), AIX, Linux and Solaris. The Darwin module probably works on *BSD.

Answer (score 3):

There really isn't a portable way to do this so you'll need to deal with platform-specific code.

On OS X, the simplest and most reliable way to get disk volume information at the command level is to use the `-plist` option for `diskutil list`.  The output can then be processed directly in Python with the `plistlib` module.  For example:

```
diskutil list -plist | \
   python -c 'import sys,plistlib,pprint; pprint.pprint(plistlib.readPlist(sys.stdin))'
{'AllDisks': ['disk0', 'disk0s1', 'disk0s2', 'disk0s3', 'disk1'],
 'AllDisksAndPartitions': [{'Content': 'GUID_partition_scheme',
                            'DeviceIdentifier': 'disk0',
                            'Partitions': [{'Content': 'EFI',
                                            'DeviceIdentifier': 'disk0s1',
                                            'Size': 209715200},
                                           {'Content': 'Apple_CoreStorage',
                                            'DeviceIdentifier': 'disk0s2',
                                            'Size': 499248103424},
                                           {'Content': 'Apple_Boot',
                                            'DeviceIdentifier': 'disk0s3',
                                            'Size': 650002432,
                                            'VolumeName': 'Recovery HD'}],
                            'Size': 500107862016},
                           {'Content': 'Apple_HFSX',
                            'DeviceIdentifier': 'disk1',
                            'MountPoint': '/',
                            'Size': 499097100288,
                            'VolumeName': 'main'}],
 'VolumesFromDisks': ['main'],
 'WholeDisks': ['disk0', 'disk1']}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this works in OS X, but one way in Linux to programmatically get if a device is mounted and on which paths is through the dbus [`org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device`](http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/udisks/Device.html) interface:

```
import sys, dbus

device_name = sys.argv[1]

bus = dbus.SystemBus()
ud_manager_obj = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", "/org/freedesktop/UDisks")
ud_manager = dbus.Interface(ud_manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks')

device = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UDisks',
                        '/org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/{0}'.format(device_name))
device_properties = dbus.Interface(device, dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE)
if device_properties.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', 'DeviceIsMounted'):
    for mount_path in device_properties.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', 'DeviceMountPaths'):
        print mount_path
```

Answer (score 1):

What about reading `/etc/mtab` and `/etc/fstab`?

I don't know OSX, but that's the standard Unix way to know what is mounted where. `mtab` should list all mounted filesystems, `fstab` should list all predefined mountpoints (which may or may not actually be mounted).

Comment: Well, it's the standard Linux way. `mtab` doesn't exist on FreeBSD, Mac OS X or Solaris. The former two have the `getfsstat(2)` and `getmntinfo(2)` system calls; on Solaris you can use `getmntent(3C)`. Unfortunately the list of currently-mounted filesystems is not defined by POSIX AFAIK, so it is wildly different on different platforms.