# Python list mounted CIFs

Tags: python

Is there any way or module in Python 2.7 that will return all the Linux-mounted Cifs (Ubuntu), something like `mount -t-cifs` return but without executing the command in the operating system?

Comment: You can't do it without either a) reimplementing the command in C, and interfacing it with python (which will be virtually the same thing as running it) or b) running the command via subprocess. You have to ask kernel for such information, and apart from using `mount` I can't see any sane options for this.

Comment: The accepted answer on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8785217/3545273) suggest to parse `/etc/mtab`...

Comment: Tks all...  Both ideas have good advantages